# Run both client and server apps at same time IIS Express for local development

Tags: node.js, reactjs, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019, iis-express

I have a Visual Studio 2019 Project that has both a ReactJS client app in ClientApp folder and a .Net Core 3.1 Entity Framework app in the same solution. The client side ReactJS app uses the controllers on the .NetCore side to manage the data.

For example, one way the ReactJS Client-side app gets data from the .NetCore API is like this:

```
const getPlayerStats = async (onlineVal) => {
  const apiResult = await axios("api/gamerStats/", {
    params: {
      isOnline: onlineVal
    }
  });
  return apiResult;
};
```

On my Windows Server using IIS, it runs both fine.

However, when I try and debug the solution locally, it fires up IIS Express but only the .Net Core Entity Framework is running.

If I start the app using `npm init` from the ClientApp folder, it starts the ReactJS part, but then the .NetCore Entity Framework app is not running.

How can I debug locally so that both parts of the solution are running and can talk to each other?

Thanks!

Comment: Are they running on the same port?

Comment: @ShakHam No when I start the ReactJS client app it runs on port 3000.  When I start the .NetCore app it runs on a different port, 5772 I think.

Comment: When you start visual studio does it stops the one started with npm?

Comment: @ShakHam no it just starts the .NetCore Entity Framework part.